# A semaphore which issues permits based on condition of permits already issued

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I've code which calculates 3D surfaces by dividing the 3D domain into block and performs some relatively expensive operation on each block. I'm trying to parallelize it using a number of worker threads to processing the blocks. An important condition is that no two workers process adjacent blocks at the same time.

I've achieved a good amount of parallelization by dividing the domain into eight with each worker processing 1/8th of the domain and using a Semaphore to control access to the "danger zone" where two workers might conflict.

```
static final Semaphore available = new Semaphore(1, true);
class BoxGenerator implements Runnable {
    ...
    void find_box(Box box) {
        if(in_danger_zone(box)) {
            try {
                available.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        do_expensive_action(box);

        if(in_danger_zone(box)) {
             available.release();
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is have a smarter method of issuing permits. Something like

```
for each current permit issued:
    if safe_to_proceed(current_permit,box) the OK
    else block
```

and hopefully use a higher level abstraction like Semaphore rather than having to ensure I get lower level code with wait() or Condition.await() correct.

A 2D permit might be to issue a permit if the x,y of the requested item is not within 1 of the coordinates of any current task.

---

Here is my first attempt, it solves the problem preventing conflicts, but all the locks degrade all the performance gains.

```
public class PermitIssuer<T> {

    final BiPredicate<T,T> predicate;
    final Collection<T> current ; 
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition hold = lock.newCondition();


    public PermitIssuer(BiPredicate<T, T> predicate,int size) {
        super();
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.current = new ArrayBlockingQueue<T>(size);
    }

    boolean safeToIssuePermit(final T requester) {
        boolean safe = current.stream().allMatch(t -> predicate.test(t,requester));
        return safe;
    }

    public void aquire(final T requester) {
        while(true) {
            if(safeToIssuePermit(requester)) {
                current.add(requester);
                return;
            }
            lock.lock();
            try {
                hold.awaitUninterruptibly();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public void release(final T requester) {
        current.remove(requester);
        lock.lock();
        try {
            hold.signalAll();
        } finally { 
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this with fewer thread than blocks? If you are, maybe you could issue a lock per block. Then if a thread is denied a lock it could just move to the next block and try to acquire the lock on that. The last code block seems to indicate that a thread is blocked while trying to acquire the lock.

Comment: The number of potential blocks is very high, in the order of 100,000, and the number of threads low 8. So the chance of a conflict is low  and they may not yet exists when . Also the logic of what to block is

Comment: I didn't understand that last when.. and is.. :) But it seems that you're doing the calculation of safe anytime a thread wants a new block to compute. Maybe you could do it without any locks at all. And just keep two separate synchronized arrays of 1) available blocks and 2) being calculated blocks

Comment: Sorry, hit return before finishing my comment.

The number of potential blocks is very high, in the order of 100,000, and the number of threads low 8. So the chance of a conflict is low, hence I'm not too concerned about a bit of blocking. Also the neighbouring blocks probably don't yet exist. 
But your idea has some merit, maybe I could use a ConcurrentHashMap to store blocking permits.